# Best way to organize filetype settings in .vim and .vimrc?

Tags: file-type, vim, ftplugin

I'm going through my vim dotfiles to tidy them up. I've noticed that through time I've added various filetype specific settings in various inconsistent ways. Let's suppose I'm customizing for Python:

- `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py (do something)`. I don't like this because some Python files might not have the .py termination.
- `au FileType python (do something)`. This seems a better option because it doesn't depend on the file having the .py termination. The drawback is that Vim doesn't know about some filetypes. I can make Vim recognize additional filetypes, but I also have various inconsistent ways of doing it: a `.vim/filetype.vim` file, another in `.vim/after/filetype.vim` and various `set filetype` commands in `.vimrc`.
- Add a `.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` file with filetype specific settings. I understand the `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim` can override whatever settings I make here. One problem is that I'm not sure how this interacts with `.vim/filetype.vim` and `.vim/after/filetype.vim`.
- Add a `.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`. I understand that this is loaded after `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim` so it can overwrite settings from there. As in the previous method I'm not sure how it interacts with the `filetype.vim` files.

So I have at least four ways of doing this, not mentioning syntax files and filetype-specific plugins. It seems to me the best way to do this is to put my filetype specific settings in `after/ftplugin` so they don't get overwritten, and `filetypes.vim` in `after` for the same reason.

However, before I proceed I'd like to ask if anyone has suggestions about the best way to deal with filetype specific settings.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I store my Python-specific settings is in [`$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`](https://github.com/johnsyweb/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim), since I do nothing to conflict with [`$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/syntax/python.vim?).

Keeping these settings in an [`ftplugin`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#ftplugin) file keeps [my `.vimrc`](https://github.com/johnsyweb/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) nice and generic and easier to maintain (it's still pretty big after over ten years of Vim usage).

If you want to [overrule](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#ftplugin-overrule) what the `ftplugin`s with your Vim distribution set up, then `$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` is what you want, as it is read *`after`* these.

Similarly `$HOME/.vim/filetype.vim` will be sourced before `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` and that in turn will be sourced before `$HOME/.vim/after/filetype.vim`.

Invoking [`:scriptnames`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:scriptnames) will list all sourced script names, in the order they were first sourced.

[`:help filetype`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#filetype) provides pretty comprehensive information on all of this.

Comment: Just want to add a note here that not all your settings must be in a single file for a filetype, they can be in a directory named after the filetype.  I have my python settings (and plugins specific to python) in .vim/ftplugin/python/{pydoc.vim, python.vim, etc..}

Comment: +1: Great point if you have a lot of different settings for a given filetype this is a really neat way to organise them.

Comment: If you keep your dotfiles under source control, this makes it easier to keep keep all of your dotfiles up-to-date, too.

Comment: ooh, `:scriptnames` is nice. In fact it gives me a pretty good idea of what the hell vim is doing with all my setting files. @Randy, that's a good suggestion, I have way too much stuff for some filetypes. Oh and of course I've got everything under git :)

Comment: So what I'm doing seems reasonable. `scriptnames` is a pretty good way to debug this if I run into trouble.

Comment: If you like `scriptnames`, you will *love* `:verbose`. Try something like `:verbose set makeprg`.

Comment: Huh, that's cool. Better not crank it up to 11 because `verbose = 10` is way too much information.

Comment: Randy mentioned you can use .vim/ftplugin/python/*, but you can also make your scripts start with the filetype: .vim/ftplugin/python_*.vim

Good for splitting out your python settings from python-vim code.

Comment: `:help filename` returns help on the `:filename` command for me. Did you mean `:help filetype`?