# Vim: Syntax file not loaded automatically

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

My `~/.vimrc` contains the following line:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.fsh,*.vsh setf glsl
```

My `~/.vim/syntax` directory contains `glsl.vim` that works if loaded manually (`:setf glsl` in Vim), but it doesn't load automatically when editing a file with those extensions. How do I get syntax highlighting for those files automatically? Syntax highlighting works for other files as usual. My Vim version is 7.4 running on Linux Mint.

Comment: This might be a shot in the dark but: have you tried using the extended form `set filetype=glsl` instead of `setf glsl`?

Comment: @Nadir Sampaoli:  That is not an "extended form," it is a different command.  See `:help :setf`.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine:  What happens with `:e foo.fsh` and then `:verbose set ft?`?  How about `:verbose au BufNewFile *.fsh`?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that line can be in your `~/.vimrc`.  Due to loading order, it may have to be in [`~/.vim/filetype.vim`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Filetype.vim) instead.  Try putting this into that file:

```
augroup filetypedetect
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.fsh,*.vsh setf glsl
augroup END
```

Comment: VIM commands can be in .vimrc. That's the whole point of its existence.

Comment: Vim commands *can* be in .vimrc, but they can also be elsewhere.  File type commands are supposed to be in filetype.vim, and I've had issues trying to force it into .vimrc in the past.  This is because load order can matter, as implied by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889766/best-way-to-organize-filetype-settings-in-vim-and-vimrc).

Comment: Tried adding it to `/usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim`. After I put `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.fsh,*.vsh setf glsl` in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`, it worked.